# Logging to php error_log in Windows 7

Tags: php, log4php

I want my log4php logger to log to the same logfile that error_log() logs to - under Windows.
I've had this working on previous (much older) versions of log4php using the config below.

However now I can't read the file due to permission errors and apache hangs
Chmoding the file under cygwin doesn't help.

Any ideas why this is so?

```
; Rolling file appender
log4php.appender.rollingFile=LoggerAppenderRollingFile
log4php.appender.rollingFile.File=log/php-error.log
log4php.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=30000KB
log4php.appender.rollingFile.Append=true
log4php.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4php.appender.rollingFile.layout=LoggerLayoutPattern
log4php.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{d-M-Y H:i:s}] [%p] %c:%L [%F:%L] %n  %m %n
```

Comment: Your "current" and "much older" references to versions are not really nailing it down. I'd suppose the rolling file appender has issues with the rights in the "log" directory, but there is no evidence whatsoever for this thesis.